# How to push int in vector<vector<int> >

Tags: c++, vector

Hey Guys I got the following problem, I implemented an graph by

```
int v= 26;
vector<int> adj[v];
```

And I'm pushing my values like this in this adjacency list:

```
void add_edge_directed(vector<int> adj[], int src, int dest)
{
    adj[src].push_back(dest);
}
```

This runs great but I have the problem that my array is a static value not a dynamic value. So I thought it would be nice to have a vector> which expands dynamic. So I tried this

```
vector< vector<int> > adj;
```

and I tried to push values in it with this:

```
void add_edge_vec(vector<vector<int> >adj, int src, int dest)
{
    adj[src].push_back(dest);
}
```

So I have no building errors but then my qtcreator in debugger mode says:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating
>   System Signal name: SIGSEGV Signal meaning: Segmentation Fault

The Debugger shows me the error in the stl_vector.h in the line 915

```
      push_back(const value_type& __x)
  {
if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
  {
    _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                             __x);
    ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
  }
```

So I have no idea what I am doing wrong. It would be great if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at least i want to post my finished solution for this Problem

```
int main()
{
   vector<vector<uint32_t>> adj;
   uint32_t segmentCount = 7;
   vector<uint32_t> preset = {0,1, 1,2, 0,3, 4,5, 5,6};
   createGraph(preset,adj,segmentCount);
```

}

now im adding the vector with

```
void createGraph(vector<uint32_t> preset ,vector<vector<uint32_t>> &adj,uint32_t segmentCount){
    uint32_t k=1;
    while (!preset.empty()){
        uint32_t src = preset.front();
        preset.erase(preset.begin());
        uint32_t dest = preset.front();
        preset.erase(preset.begin());
        addEdgeDirected(adj,src,dest);
        ++k;
    }

}
```

and now im pushing the vectors in with emplacing back an initializer list.

```
void addEdgeDirected(vector<vector<uint32_t>> &adj, uint32_t src, uint32_t dest)
{
    adj.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<uint32_t>{ });
    adj.at(src).push_back(dest);
}
```

thank you all for your help!

Comment: A couple of details: **1.** this doesn't compile, there's a typo in  `addEdgeDirected(vec;0;1);` it shoul be `,` instead of `;`. **2.** Also this doesn't solve the segmentation fault problem you were having, for example right after you create the vector `vec`  `vector<vector<uint32_t>>vec;`, try calling `addEdgeDirected(vec, 2, 1);`.

Comment: so i edited it with my code which is running and in added another function.

Comment: If you have `pre-settings`, then you know the size =], and if you know the size, then you can create `adj` with that given size in `1` line of code. One thing you can do in `addEdgeDirected` is  to check if `src` is greater than the `size` of `ajd` and then you can `emplace` items while you've reached that size then segfault is gone and presets are not needed since your container will grow to accommodate `src` amount of elements.

Answer (score 4):

`vector<vector<int>> adj;` creates an vector `adj` of size `0` so when you try accessing a value from it:

```
void add_edge_directed(vector<int> adj[], int src, int dest)
{
    // adj size = 0
    // this will cause a seg fault since you are trying 
    // to access an element at index src which is outside
    // of the vector
    adj[src].push_back(dest);
}
```

In the case of the array of vectors, you were initializing the array to have `v` elements:

```
vector<int> adj[v];
```

So in the case of the vector, you can use

```
vector<vector<int>> adj(v);
```

This will create a `vector` with `v` vectors of size `0`. Now you can rewrite your `add_edge_directed` as follows:

```
// pass adj by reference (vector<vector<int>>&) to avoid creating 
// a copy of adj each time the function is called
void add_edge_directed(vector<vector<int>>& adj, int src, int dest)
{
    adj[src].push_back(dest);
}
```

Comment: Er, don't forget the need to pass by reference.

Comment: So its not possbile to create the <vector<vector<int>> with a dynamic length? Because I don't want to say the vector how long it should be, his size should extend automatically with my Pushbacks.

Comment: @TimKrzyzanowski it is possible, in fact in all of your inner vectors, you are calling `push_back` and it's working fine. `push_back` tries to add the element to the vector and if there's not enough space it will grow the container. The problem arises when you try to access an element i.e. `vector[10]` but the vector has say 2 elements. So before you can get vectors from adj, you need to call `push_back` on adj, `adj.push_back(vector<int>{})` will add a vector to `adj`

Comment: @StaticBeagle oh ok so i just need an if which looks if there is an vector on my adj[src] and if not I pusback a vector<int>. Thank you very much you saved my day.

Comment: @TimKrzyzanowski Well, if the vector is empty you will have to push `src + 1` vectors into `adj` before you can use `adj[src]`. The vector is backed by an array internally so just think of getting elements out of that internal array which is zero based meaning the index starts at `0` (array[0]). In summary, just make sure there's something in there before you try to get that something out.